# Tagged PDF using an HTML to PDF Converter such as Winnovative

Tags: pdf, accessibility, winnovative, tagged-pdf

There are many converter available on the market to create and manipulate PDF file from a simple HTML/CSS page. These tools are very convenient to create quickly some nice PDF files without the hassle of the more complex reporting tools of this world.

I am using Winnovative software to achieve this goal but I was wondering how to create accessible file (tagged PDF) to improve text-to-speach tool processing.

Are there any HTML tags that exists to achieve this? Anybody has some experience with this kind of requirements?

Answer (score 4):

The tool itself has to be able to support the pdf/ua spec (tagged pdf).  The list of possible PDF tags corresponds nicely to html tags.  For example, there are `<h1>` through `<h6>` tags, table tags (`<table>, <th>, <tr>, <td>`), list tags (`<l>, <li>`), and so on.

There are minor differences, such as the tag to start a list is `<l>` instead of html's `<ul>` or `<ol>`.  With a PDF document, the screen reader will say "list with 3 items" and then you navigate through each item.  It doesn't seem to care if it's bulleted or numbered, thus the reason pdf/ua has `<l>` and html has `<ol>` and `<ul>`.

Anyway, the point is you don't need to use any special html tags to generate tagged pdf.  The tool that generates the pdf just needs to support pdf/ua.  I didn't see anything on Winnovative's website that indicated it support it.

FYI, here are the tags available in PDF/UA

```
<Art>
<Annot>
<BibEntry>
<BlockQuote>
<Caption>
<Code>
<Div>
<Document>
<Figure>
<Form>
<Formula>
<H>
<H1>
<H2>
<H3>
<H4>
<H5>
<H6>
<Index>
<Lbl>
<Link>
<L>
<LI>
<Lbody>
<Note>
<P>
<Part>
<Quote>
<Reference>
<Sect>
<Span>
<Table>
<TD>
<TH>
<TOC>
<TOCI>
<TR>
```

Comment: Do you have any other converter in mind that supports this PDF/UA? Preferably compatible with .NET or Java. Even the more expensive tools such as Aspose PDF do not support it yet, so I am a bit in the dark as to how to achieve this goal.

Comment: @JayMF did you find any HTML to PDF/UA converted?

Comment: @tepez Sorry for late answer but nope. We are still using Winnovative without tagging.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @JayMF!

Answer (score 2):

[Essential PDF](https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/working-with-tagged-pdf) supports generating tagged PDF when converting from HTML to PDF using the Internet Explorer MSHTML engine.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Answer (score 0):

Good explanation in slugolicious' answer about tagging PDF. While researching accessible PDF output for a project I found PDFReactor (www.pdfreactor.com) can do this. Unfortunately there's no budget for a license in this project right now, so I haven't tested it in production, but have tried the free personal version with satisfying results.